# I am looking for a Sci-Fi book about starships that cause supernovas

Tags: story-identification

I read a book ages ago and am looking for it again but can't seem to get google to chuck it up from my search terms.

What I can remember of it is that there is a female lead character and she discovers a secret about an alien race. This race is the only one in the galaxy that has FTL and transports around other races (or just humans - I don't remember) but it turns out in the past they they'd used the starship's FTL drives to cause supernovas and wipe out the race that used to have the technology in a massive genocide.

Opening of the book is about humans looking at the stars and noticing a lot of them blink out of existence in a certain area of space.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Random related bit: the Larry Niven short-story/novelette "The Fourth Profession" features a lightsail starship that takes a boost either from a laser battery provided by the host civilization or from an induced nova of the local star.

Comment: Another random bit: astronomers have noticed clustering of novas in the sky (see http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/observing-news/yet-another-nova-in-sagittarius/).  Initially the astronomers thought the novas were advancing towards Earth.  Several SF stories have cashed in on the topic proposing various SF reasons for that observation.

Later observations indicated a more random distribution of novas - blowing those stories out of the water.

Comment: A recent story I read that used this meme was one of the Carrier Strike books by Ian Douglas (http://www.amazon.com/Earth-Strike-Star-Carrier-Series/dp/0061840254) but I think you can find the idea in many different books.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: Stealing Light by Gary Gibson - Book Cover]

Could be ["**Stealing Light**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?659521) by Gary Gibson.

It's the first book in ["**The Shoal Sequence**"](http://www.goodreads.com/series/67700-the-shoal-sequence) series. Here's what the [blurb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1447224094) says:

> In the 25th century, *only the Shoal possess the secret of
> faster-than-light travel (FTL)*, giving them absolute control over all
> trade and exploration throughout the galaxy.
>
> Mankind has operated within their influence for two centuries,
> establishing a dozen human colony worlds scattered along Shoal trade
> routes.
>
> Dakota Merrick, while serving as a military pilot, has witnessed
> atrocities for which this alien race is responsible. Now piloting a
> civilian cargo ship, *she is currently ferrying an exploration team*
> to a star system containing a derelict starship. From its wreckage,
> her passengers hope to salvage a functioning FTL drive of mysteriously
> non-Shoal origin.
>
> But the Shoal are not yet ready to relinquish their monopoly over a
> *technology they acquired through ancient genocide.*

From a [review](http://vastandcool.blogspot.com/2011/02/book-review-stealing-light-by-gary.html), the part where the humans spot a disturbance in space:

> This starts off early, with the revelation that *humans had recently
> detected a massive series of supernovae in the Large Magellanic
> Cloud.* In addition to creating a sense of foreboding and mystery, it
> drives home the inhumanly vast scope of events, in both time and
> space - it took 160,000 years for the light from this catastrophe to
> reach human territory...

An [extract](http://torbooks.co.uk/2013/05/09/gary-gibsons-shoal-series-the-five-question-interview/) from the book describing it:

> *The first supernova had appeared six years before*, early in the autumn, and just a couple of days after Dakota’s sixteenth birthday.
> It had blossomed like cold fire, briefly one of the brightest elements
> in the night sky, before gradually fading out over the following
> weeks. Then, over the next several years, *dozens more had appeared at
> irregular intervals*, shining brightly for a few brief weeks before
> again fading back into stellar anonymity. And *all this had occurred
> within a relatively tiny sector* of a neighbouring galaxy.

<sup>*~ Cover image from [SfReviews.net](http://www.sfreviews.net/ggibson_stealing_light.html)*</sup>

Comment: You beautiful, beautiful person! This is exactly what I was after.